# How to draw multiple colored bars in a table?

Tags: tables, color, cline

For a calendar, I would like to draw multiple lines indicating things like school breaks into a table. A single calendar day is already multiple cells in the table, so I thought using `\arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{1-5}` for that, but the problem is that `\cline` does not stack like `\hline` and therefore there can only be one line on a given day.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}   % »table« optons loads »colortbl« package

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}\hline
  & Monday &  &  & Thuesday & \\
  \hline\hline
  1&2&3&4&5&6 \\
  \cline{2-5}\arrayrulecolor{green} \cline{2-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
  &&&&&&
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The second (green) `\cline{2-3}` overwrites the first `\cline{2-5}` for the first two cells, instead of being positioned below the first like the second `\hline` below the header.

(I am actually not too attached to the `\cline` solution, it just seems to be the most obvious way to format the calendar.)

Comment: There's a TikZ calendar library which might work out for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `matrix of nodes`. it is possible to use fairly intuitive syntax so that you can produce something like:

[image]

using code like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}   % »table« optons loads »colortbl« package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        G/.append style = {fill=ForestGreen!10},
        R/.append style = {fill=Red!10, text=Red},
        V/.append style = {fill=BlueViolet!10},
      ]
      \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
         every node/.style = {anchor=base,text depth=.5ex,text height=2ex,
                            text width=20mm, rectangle, draw=SkyBlue},
         row 1/.style = {every node/.append style={fill=SkyBlue!20}, 
                         font=\bfseries, Blue, minimum height=2em},
       ]{%
        Monday       & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday   & Friday & Saturday & Sunday\\
        |[G]|Holiday & Work    & Work      & |[R]| Sick & Work   &  Work& Work \\
        |[V]|Meeting & Lunch   & Work      & |[R]| Sick & Work   &  Work& Work \\
       };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `G`, `R` and `V` styles are examples that to show you how to define "shorthands"  that add particular styling to certain cells. Of course, many things are possible. I don't know the `tikz calendar` library referred in the comments, so perhaps it gives a nicer way of doing this.

I think that the styling is "better" than what you were asking for, but if instead of shading you prefer using coloured lines this is easy to do using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). The `M` in the `\matrux(M)...` allows you to refer to the cells in the matrix by their row and column indices so, for example `(M-2-1)` is the cell in row 2 and column 1.  As a slight variation of the above, you can produce

[image]

by adding the two lines

```
\draw[red, thick](M-2-1.south east)--(M-2-2.south east);
\draw[blue, thick](M-3-2.south east)--(M-3-3.south east);
```

a the bottom of the `tikzpicture` environment.

**Edit**

I quite like this code so I wanted to extend this idea and make it into an environment. Unfortunately, because of the inner working of the `\matrix of nodes` this means that the `&` column separators need to be replaced by `\&`. I also added some trickery for underlining cells that uses the same syntax for changing the background colour of a cell. With these changes, the code

```
\begin{Table}
    Monday       \& Tuesday \& Wednesday \& Thursday   \& Friday  \\
    |[G]|Holiday \& Work    \& Work      \& |[R]| Sick \& Work    \\
    |[V]|Meeting \& Lunch   \&|[b,V]|Work\& |[R]| Sick \&|[b]|Work\\
\end{Table}
```

now produces

[image]

As the example shows, it is possible to combine different styles.

Here is the revised code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}   % »table« optons loads »colortbl« package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{
    G/.append style = {fill=ForestGreen!10},
    R/.append style = {fill=Red!10, text=Red},
    blue underline/.style={blue, thick},
    V/.append style = {fill=BlueViolet!10},
    b/.code = {
      \def\row{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
      \def\col{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
      \xappto\AfterThoughts{\noexpand\draw[blue underline](M-\row-\col.south west)--(M-\row-\col.south east);}
    }
}
\NewEnviron{Table}{%
    \def\AfterThoughts{}%
    \tikzpicture
      \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
         ampersand replacement=\&,
         every node/.style = {anchor=base,text depth=.5ex,text height=2ex,
                            text width=20mm, rectangle, draw=SkyBlue},
         row 1/.style = {every node/.append style={fill=SkyBlue!20},
                         font=\bfseries, Blue, minimum height=2em},
       ]{\BODY};\AfterThoughts\endtikzpicture}

\begin{document}

  \begin{Table}
    Monday       \& Tuesday \& Wednesday \& Thursday   \& Friday  \\
    |[G]|Holiday \& Work    \& Work      \& |[R]| Sick \& Work    \\
    |[V]|Meeting \& Lunch   \&|[b,V]|Work\& |[R]| Sick \&|[b]|Work\\
  \end{Table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have directly the expected output because, in that environment the behaviour of `\cline` has been corrected.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}   % »table« optons loads »colortbl« package
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|ccc|ccc|}\hline
  & Monday &  &  & Thuesday & \\
  \hline\hline
  1&2&3&4&5&6 \\
  \cline{2-5}\arrayrulecolor{green} \cline{2-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
  &&&&& \\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]