# Row color complete

Tags: tables, color, tabularx

I have a problem with the color of the rows and I have searched and tried several solutions and I have not been successful. I can set the color of the row without problem, but the colo does not occupy the entire row, leaving a margin up and down unpainted. How can I make it to paint everything?

I use MacTex with Texmaker.

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\normalfont
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,font={footnotesize},skip=0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{40,112,60}
\definecolor{blanco}{RGB}{254,254,254}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccc}
\toprule[0.5mm]
\multicolumn{14}{>{\columncolor{verde}}c}{\textcolor{blanco}{\textbf{Parámetros climáticos promedio}}}\\
\midrule[0.3mm]
Mes & Ene & Feb & Mar & Abr & May & Jun & Jul & Ago & Sep & Oct & Nov & Dic & Anual\\
\midrule[0.1mm]
Máx. media ($^\circ$C) & 15 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 15 & 14 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 18 & 18 & 17 & 15,8\\
Media ($^\circ$C) & 9 & 9 & 9 & 8,5 & 6,5 & 5,5 & 5,5 & 5 & 6 & 6,5 & 9,5 & 10 & 10\\
Mín. Media ($^\circ$C) & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & -2 & -3 & -4 & -3 & -1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0,1\\
Precip. (mm) & 92 & 86 & 55 & 13 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 10 & 20 & 38 & 75 & 397\\  
Días $\geq$ 1mm & 17 & 16 & 12 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 14 & 80\\  
\bottomrule[0.5mm]
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Datos climáticos promedio de San Cristóbal de Lípez}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365685/117534 for example. welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Another approach would be to use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421922/how-to-draw-multiple-colored-bars-in-a-table

Comment: this is space added by booktabs as shown in the answer in Troy's comment. Unrelated but avoid using `\resizebox` with tables: it leads to inconsistent font sizes and rule widths.