# Creating specific table in latex

Tags: tables

I want to replicate a table as shown in the below figure[image]

Best I was able to do is this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Interpretation of $\kappa$ coeff. \cite{KappaPaper}}
\begin{tabular}{c  l}
$\kappa$ coeff. & Agreement \\
\hline
$\leq$ 0 & Less than chance Agreement\\
0.01 to 0.20 & Slight Agreement\\
0.21 to 0.40 & Fair Agreement\\
0.41 to 0.60 & Moderate Agreement\\
0.61 to 0.80 & Substantial Agreement\\
0.81 to 0.99 & Almost Perfect Agreement\\
\end{tabular}
\label{table:kappa_stats}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which turns out to be like this.

[image]

Any idea on how I should go about getting the legend thing?

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear to me. Can you be more specific.

Comment: In the first image, there is an indication of Poor, Slight, Fair ... for kappa values. I want to create that in latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want an arrow head possibly the easiest way is to use a `matrix of nodes` from [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). This let's you produce:

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Interpretation of $\kappa$ coeff. \cite{KappaPaper}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,]
      { & Poor & Slight & Fair & Moderate & Substantial & Almost perfect\\
        Kappa & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.40 & 0.60 & 0.80 & 1.0\\
      };
      \draw[thick, -latex](M-2-2.north west)--([xshift=30]M-2-7.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
      \underline{$\kappa$ coeff.} & \underline{Agreement}\\
        $\leq$ 0 & Less than chance Agreement\\
        0.01 to 0.20 & Slight Agreement\\
        0.21 to 0.40 & Fair Agreement\\
        0.41 to 0.60 & Moderate Agreement\\
        0.61 to 0.80 & Substantial Agreement\\
        0.81 to 0.99 & Almost Perfect Agreement\\
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:kappa_stats}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using a `matrix of nodes` for tables is quite powerful if you want to add styling. See, for example, [How to draw multiple colored bars in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421922/how-to-draw-multiple-colored-bars-in-a-table).

Comment: +1 for using matrix in tikz.